# Как разместить по середине ActionBara TextView?

Tags: android, java

Как разместить по середине ActionBara TextView?

```
setCusomView у getActionBara не работает

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="my Title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Он не может не работать.

Comment: Ну а вообще можно MenuItem на всю ширину Actionbar'а с центрированием по ширине, а у ActionBar'а скрыть Title

Comment: @Suvitruf, Я использую такой метод, который выше написал. Но все Ок, Только вот почему то Title пропадает. А мне с ним надо. Как же быть?

Comment: @Futurama вы хотите Title посередине AB? Или вы хотите свой кастомный Title посередине AB? Или вы хотите стандартный Title + ваш TextView посередине оставшегося свободного места в AB?